# Can't use bx plugin repo-add

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-plugin

When I try this:

```
bx plugin repo-add CF-Community http://plugins.cloudfoundry.org
```

I get:

```
FAILED
An error occurred when obtaining plug-ins from the repository.
Error response from server. Status code: 404; message: 404 page not 
found
```

Try again later.

I also tried:

```
bx plugin install http://plugins.cloudfoundry.org/cf-download
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can add cloud foundry plugins that way:

```
$ BLUEMIX_TRACE=true bx plugin repo-add CF-Community https://plugins.cloudfoundry.org

REQUEST: [2017-07-10T19:02:31+01:00]
GET /bx/list HTTP/1.1
Host: plugins.cloudfoundry.org
...
```

Notice the GET request is to `GET /bx/list`.  This makes me think the `bx` plugin repositories are incompatible with `cf` plugin repositories.

You could try:

```
bx cf add-plugin-repo CF-Community https://plugins.cloudfoundry.org
```